# The Screen/Mix Compositing nodes cant fully mix two image sequences/videos together

Tags: rendering, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes

[image: Image for clarification:]

There is the real time video and an image sequence of an animated lightsaber. They are connected through a Screen node to the composite and viewer nodes. The original image sequence of the animated light saber doesnt have the light saber transparent. It is fully blue and glowing. But here upon being mixed in, it becomes transparent so that you can see the stick my cousin was wielding in the real time video. Changing the factor lower makes the saber more visible than the video, but that darkens the background video. I want the video and the saber in their original opacities. Any ideas?

Comment: If the light saber is rendered with alpha (Output style PNG with RGB*A*), then try connecting the Alpha output from your composit node to the Factor input of the following node or perhaps check "Use Alpha" on the output node.  Some combination of that should work for you.

Comment: The lightsaber was rendered as a PNG image sequence with RGB. Rendering it with RGBA made it further transparent and harder to work with. Messing with the use alpha buttons and their values didnt help either